# How to jump to notification screen when click on notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I setup notification system with firebase and react native. It's working fine, but when i receive notification in any state of app(killed, fore or background) and do click notification push me to home screen. I want to go on notification screen when someone click on notification.
How it will possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to add a Firebase Notification listener at the top-level component. I'll suggest placing it in App.js.

1. [Foreground Listener](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#foreground-state-messages)
2. [Background Listener](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background--quit-state-messages)

After that, You have to navigate to a particular screen with the help of a navigation prop. if you place the listener at App.js then you will not have access to the navigation prop since App.js will return the navigation container.
For that, you have to create one helper function like this [navigation without prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)

e.g.

```
export const App = () => {
  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      navigate('Notification'); //navigate to notification screen
  });
  const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
    //generate local notification using your preferred library
    //handle navigation

  })
   
  return <RootNavigator />;
};
```